# Cannot find a way to tap() this element (wd,nodejs)

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I have a DOM like this:

```
<form id="frmResendPassword" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">...</div>
  <span class="pull-right">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
     Resend Password</button>
   </span>
 </form>
```

I want to tap the "Resend Password" button.

I have tried many different selectors such as:

```
elementByClassName("btn-default")
elementById("frmResendPassword")
elementByName("Resend Password")
elementByCss(thecsspath)
```

ect.... none of them perform the `tap()`...
however they do not throw a element not found error....
so im confused. can some one please help

update:
Here is the basic automation code... its very basic

```
  it("should send text to phone", function(){
    sleep.sleep(5)
    return browser
    .elementByName("mobileNo")
    .sendKeys(usrnme)
    .elementByCss("#frmResendPassword button[type=submit]")
    .tap()
})
```

It types the mobile number in fine, however it seems to just ignore pressing the button.

Comment: What code are you using to call the `tap()`? And what is `thecsspath`? Your other selectors are grabbing the wrong element, except for `elementByClassName("btn-default")`, but that is also likely grabbing a different button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the selector is the problem. Try this:

```
elementByCss("button[type=submit]")
```

or if that doesn't uniquely identify it, maybe this:

```
elementByCss("#frmResendPassword button[type=submit]")
```

In English that means a `button` with `type` value of `submit` that has an ancestor of a `form` where the `id`(`#`) is `frmResendPassword`

Comment: both did not work, any other ideas? im seriously stuck on this simple task

Comment: Interesting, `tap` can be a little finicky, I know people have used a lot of workarounds to make it more solid, but I thought it was better by now. Glad you got it to work with `click`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it, thanks to mrfreester

```
 it("should send text to phone", function(){
sleep.sleep(5)
return browser
.elementByName("mobileNo")
.sendKeys(usrnme)
.elementByCss("#frmResendPassword button[type=submit]")
.click()
```

})